# Groupby to Identify minimum dates for each group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to write a lambda function in pandas that allows me to identify the minimum "date" of a subgroup of data. I'm trying to use a lambda function and pandas groupby to solve this.
Code:

```
df['min_asd'] = df.anticipatedstartdate.map(
lambda x: 1 if df.groupby('learners_id').anticipatedstartdate == x.min() else 0)
```

The goal is to get the minimum date BY the learners id (student id), not the golbal minimum date.

The error message I receive:

> TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not callable

Comment: `df['min_asd'] = df.groupby('learners_id')['anticipatedstartdate'].transform('min')` ?

Comment: Please reference this on how to create a StackOverFlow post as it's impossible for me to know if ^^^ is the correct answer without testing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use the `map()` function in conjugation with the `groupby()` function like that. The `map()` function takes a lambda which expects a single value (`x`) for each row of the series (`anticipatedstartdate`). That means it is just one `Timestamp` and because of that it does not have a `max()` aggregation function like you'd expect of a (numpy) array. What it does have is a `max` property on the class level, which the `x` object gladly provides. This is simply the constant `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')` defined [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html).

The reason you are getting the error:

> TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not callable

Is that this max constant timestamp isn't callable, because it is just an object which does not have the `__call__()` function implemented. When trying to use an object as a function python tries to use the `__call__()` function and fails with a `TypeError`: [More about `__call__()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__call__-in-python/)

Anyway. In the future you should probably include some test data, but I think I managed to find a suitable example:

The following should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'learners_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        'anticipatedstartdate': [
            '2020-01-04',
            '2020-01-05',
            '2020-01-03',
            '2020-01-07',
            '2020-01-01',
            '2020-01-08',
            '2020-01-09',
            '2020-01-06',
            '2020-01-02',
        ]
    }
)
df['anticipatedstartdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['anticipatedstartdate'])
df['min_asd'] = 1 * (
    df.groupby('learners_id')['anticipatedstartdate'].transform('min') == df['anticipatedstartdate']
)
```

This outputs:

```
   learners_id anticipatedstartdate  min_asd
0            1           2020-01-04        1
1            2           2020-01-05        0
2            3           2020-01-03        0
3            1           2020-01-07        0
4            2           2020-01-01        1
5            3           2020-01-08        0
6            1           2020-01-09        0
7            2           2020-01-06        0
8            3           2020-01-02        1
```

Normally you would use an aggregation function directly on the result of the `groupby()` function and the series selector (projection if you will), like this:

```
df.groupby('learners_id')['anticipatedstartdate'].min()

learners_id
1   2020-01-04
2   2020-01-01
3   2020-01-02
```

However, this aggregates the results, but what you want is to keep the results per entry so that you keep the granularity of your original dataset. This can be done using the `.transform()` function instead:

```
df.groupby('learners_id')['anticipatedstartdate'].transform('min')

0   2020-01-04
1   2020-01-01
2   2020-01-02
3   2020-01-04
4   2020-01-01
5   2020-01-02
6   2020-01-04
7   2020-01-01
8   2020-01-02
```

Now because you the minimum value of `anticipatedstartdate` for each of your original record, you can simply do an equality check on the original `anticipatedstartdate` series:

```
df.groupby('learners_id')['anticipatedstartdate'].transform('min') == df['anticipatedstartdate']

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
```

This is the result we are looking for, but it seemed like you wanted them as {0, 1} integer. It's easy to coerce bools to those by just multiplying with 1 giving you:

```
df['min_asd'] = 1 * (
    df.groupby('learners_id')['anticipatedstartdate'].transform('min') == df['anticipatedstartdate']
)
```